# Execute test in sequence in nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I wanna execute some nunit/C# tests in sequnce. I'm testing with webdriver at browserstack. and what I wan't to do is execute my test in sequence with several platforms and several devices. I tried with [TestFixture("android", "Android", "LG Nexus 4")]
    [TestFixture("android", "Samsung Galaxy S III")] and a constructor for my class. but it didn't work. Could you help me out here?

```
[TestFixture("android", "Android", "LG Nexus 4")]
[TestFixture("android", "Samsung Galaxy S III")]
public class Multi
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private string _browsername;
    private string _platform;
    private string _device;

    public void Multi(string browsername, string platform, string device)
    { 
        _browsername = browsername;
        _platform  = platform;
        _device = device;

    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "test");
        capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "test");
        capability.SetCapability("browserstack.local", "true");

        capability.SetCapability("browserName", _browsername);
        capability.SetCapability("platform", _platform);

        capability.SetCapability("device", _device);

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
          new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), capability
        );
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://sunet.se");



    }

    [Test]
    public void StartTest()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/a")).Click();

        }

    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Multi class has a constructor for the first signature (3 strings) of TestFixture but not for the second signature (two strings). Depending on your NUnit version this could explain the problem. Either add the correct constructor or change the second `TestFixture` signature

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself but there is a library you could use to do this called NUnit Sequencer.

https://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/1354.nunit-sequencer-tool-to-sequence-run-ordered-nunit-tests-and-fixtures-by-setting-attributes.aspx

It seems like a little bit of config to set it up, but it allows you to decorate your test fixtures with attributes, that specify the names of the test in the order you want to run them.

Example:

```
[TestFixture]
[SequencedTestFixture("SubtractTest", "AddTest")]
public class ArithmeticTests1
```

This would run a test called `SubtractTest` first, followed by a test called `AddTest`.

Note that unit tests are meant to be run completely independently of each other, and that's why they are usually run in illogical order (although NUnit seem to be in alphabetical order).

Actually if you didn't want to use the library I mentioned, a quick fix would be to rename your test fixtures like this `0001_DoThisThingFirst`, and `0002_DoSomethingElse` etc. -  that way NUnit will run them in alphabetical order. This could become a maintenance headache though.

Comment: Ok,well it seems like i'll be stuck with duplicate code. But that's ok for now. Thanks for answer.